# Android Studio on Windows doesn't show options related to Android Build

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.2

I downloaded [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) and through "Import Project" opened the project (Gradle.build).

- AVD Manager inactive on the Toolbar.
- Tools menu doesn't have 'Android'
- Build menu doesn't have build related options like 'Rebuild Project'

File -> Project Structure -> SDKs shows the right 'Android SDK home path' and 'Java SDK' configured.
I can run java from my Command Prompt.

Not sure if it's related, 'Settings' -> Android SDK -> 'Launch Standalone SDK Manager' isn't working. 
android.bat file under the ...sdk/tools/ ran.
But again when I open the Android Studio, none of the above changed.

What could the issue be?